# Consuming RestTemplate API response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I need same help. I have the POJO class, I need to consume the starwar API, take the result and transform it into objects.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Planeta {

private String name;
private String climate; 
private String terrain;



 Getters and Setters...
```

Application.java

```
package hello;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
    return args -> {
        Planeta planeta = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/planeta/name/terra", Planeta.class);

        log.info(planeta.getName());
    };
}
}
```

for some reason I'm getting null values.

The url api result is

```
{"data":[{"id":"5c378401c0ac520ffc670019","name":"terra","climate":"tropical","terrain":"earth"}],"erros":null}
```

**logs**

```
Application : Planeta [name=null, climate=null, terrain=null]
```

edited;

Comment: Fix the compilation error. It tells you what's is wrong with it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden

Comment: That's not a compile error.

Comment: If you're getting `403`, that means that whoever you're trying to communicate with doesn't want you doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: i changed URL api now i get null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response doesn't match to you POJO, response is `JSONObject` with `JsonArray` (key = "data") and array consists of `Planeta` objects

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response{

 @JsonProperty("data")
 List<Planeta> data;

 }
```

If you have only one `Planeta` object in `List`,

```
Planeta p = data.stream().findFirst().get();
System.out.println(p.getName());
```

If you have multiple objects in `List`

**for each**

```
for(Planeta p :data) {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        // same for climate and terrain
    }
```

**java-8**

```
data.forEach(planeta-> System.out.println(planeta.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning an object with key `data`, inside which there is an array of planets not one. You are expecting just one, without the data field. The JSON doesn't match your expected Planeta class.

Comment: believe that this is not the problem, because the api only returns 1 result, what I do not know how to do is access the key "data"

Comment: No it doesn't matter if there is 1 result. It is still an array. There is the `[` after `data:` that indicates it. To access the key data you have to do the same as you did to access the other keys `name`, `climate` and `terrain`.